# Calling a method when UIWebView scrolls

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview, scroll, method-call

I have a UIWebView that contains a lot of text content. I need to be able to get the location of the UIWebView every time it moves. I am using this code to get the point:

```
pageYOffset = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.pageYOffset"] intValue];
```

now I just need to make it so that this variables value is updated everytime the UIWebView position moves, or there is any scrolling. Is it possible to call a method whenever the UIWebView scrolls?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should extend UIWebView, like below

```
@implementation UIWebView(CustomScroll)
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    [self.delegate scrollViewDidScroll: scrollView];
}
@end
```

and implement scrollViewDidScroll on your controller like:

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    NSLog("webview scrolled");
}
```

and don't forget to set your controller to the delegate property of UIWebView.

Comment: Generally, a bad idea to extend Apple classes in such a fashion.  Be careful.

Comment: Any update for 2022 and Swift for this functionallity?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that if your header lists your VC as a UIScrollViewDelegate, you can use the 
`-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` method to find out when it scrolls.

Comment: It seems you're correct..I tried multiple techniques to achieve this, failed on all.  Sorry.

Comment: This method does work, and is a far better approach. Simply set the scrollview delegate to the view controller too.

`[webView.scrollView setDelegate:self]`

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct. If you will use:

```
@implementation UIWebView(CustomScroll)
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    [self.delegate scrollViewDidScroll: scrollView];
}
@end
```

You will lose focus when try to enter data on page on iOS7 and more

You need to implement custom class for UIWevView and overwrite scrollViewDidScroll:

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
[super scrollViewDidScroll:scrollView];
[((id<UIScrollViewDelegate>)self.delegate) scrollViewDidScroll:scrollView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your requirement is to keep loading webview when user scrolls then you should paste your code into

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```