# How do you hook up scrollViewDidScroll in a UIWebView?

Tags: xcode, ios5, uiwebview

I am trying to do an action when the UIScrollView in a UIWebView scrolls. I want to wire up the scrollViewDidScroll method to do this, but this is not exposed in the UIWebViewDelegate. I feel like I should be able to make my controller implement the UIScrollViewDelegate as well, but that seems to mess up the UIWebView because that is supposed to be the UIScrollView's delegate.

Comment: You can just extend UIWebView by making your category, [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4060249/82813) the sample

Comment: Ah! I had see that one, but tried to extend the class instead of defining it in a category. Works perfectly now.

Comment: Glad I could help, would you mind up-voting my comment?

Comment: I don't see a way to vote up a comment... if it was an answer I could mark it as accepted...

Comment: when you point over a comment you can se in front of the comment row up row arrow and flag just click on up arrow. [here's](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2176142/upvote.png) the screenshot :) thanks

Comment: I must not have enough reputation - I do not see those items there. If you re-respond as an answer I will mark it as accepted - sorry for the back and forth.

Comment: thanks :) you'll come back when you gain some reputation

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a method when UIWebView scrolls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048677/calling-a-method-when-uiwebview-scrolls)