# add implementation UIWebView(CustomScroll)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, uiwebview

I'm trying to add [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4060249/1578927) to my code

```
@implementation UIWebView(CustomScroll)
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    [self.delegate scrollViewDidScroll: scrollView];
}
@end
```

But getting "No known instance method for selector 'scrollViewDidScroll:'"
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

The [UIWebViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol does not declare a method `scrollViewDidScroll:`. Hence, this is why you're getting the bad access error.

I'd recommend that you subclass `UIWebView` instead of trying to creating a category on it (yes, the docs recommend against subclassing... just don't override any of the methods it has, and it's safe).

On your subclass, you can either create a new protocol or simply overwrite the `delegate` property to also require that it conforms to `UIScrollViewDelegate (the later is shown below):

In Example:

```
// MyWebView.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyWebView : UIWebView
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<UIWebViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate> delegate;
@end


// MyWebView.m
#import "MyWebView.h"

@implementation MyWebView

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    /* As scrollViewDidScroll: is optional, you should check if the super class
       responds to this method (it doesn't appear to now, but this may change in future) */

    if ([[self superclass] instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(scrollViewDidScroll:)])
    {
        [super scrollViewDidScroll:scrollView];
    }

    /* Likewise, you should check if your own delegate responds to this selector */

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollViewDidScroll:)])
    {
        [self.delegate scrollViewDidScroll:scrollView];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Please see edited answer with further clarification. Let me know if you still need help. :D

Comment: Thanks for the help. When I'm trying to scroll the subclassed `UIWebView` I'm getting `-[MyWebView scrollViewDidScroll:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x819cf50`

Comment: for some reason `[super scrollViewDidScroll:scrollView];` is failing?

Comment: Because as far as the compiler knows, `UIWebView` is not a `UIScrollViewDelegate`. You should be able to work around this with `@interface UIWebView(Foo)<UIScrollViewDelegate> @end`, but it's a little bit iffy (as long as you never call it yourself you should be fine, though).

Comment: @tc, actually the compiler does know... see `UIWebView.h` which shows `@interface UIWebView : UIView <NSCoding, UIScrollViewDelegate>`. Hence, there's no need to declare that your subclass conforms to `UIScrollViewDelegate` twice.

Comment: Please see the edited answer. Apparently, while `UIWebView` conforms to `UIScrollViewDelegate`, it does not implement `scrollViewDidScroll:`. However, as this may change in future (it's implementation isn't public), you should check to see if it does... see comments in code regarding such. :)

Comment: @JRG-Developer D'oh. Ignore my previous comment; the logic is completely flawed!